# Move neighboor components on JavaFx ScaleTransition

Tags: java, animation, resize, javafx-2, gridpane

I have a `GridPane` containing some `Nodes` (of unknown types). There is some nodes on the middle of this `GridPane` who should disappear progressively when a method is called (500ms).

My first step was to simply make it disappear using (each node have this method, will be called when the event to show or hide nodes occurs)

```
public void expandNode(boolean isExpanded) {
    node.setVisible(isExpanded);
    node.setManaged(isExpanded);
}
```

My second step was to use `ScaleTransition` like this:

```
public void expandNode(boolean isExpanded) {
    ScaleTransition transition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(500), node);
    transition.setToY(isExpanded?1:0);
    transition.play();
}
```

But the problem (that was corrected using `node.setManaged` when not using timed transition) is that my grid doesn't resize like it does when adding or removing nodes from it.

Lets see an example:
Action expand should hidde/expand an entire line for my grid. I want when my line is hidden, the following lines to go up, but I want that all my columns have their sizes unchanged (like if line was always here).
[image]

If you have any idea of how to do something like this, I need your help !
Thank you !

Comment: sorry but i do not still understand, you do not use setManaged again? when you say you want your columns you mean you want them to retain their width sizes how they were before scalling?

Comment: Exactly, I want column width to be the same as if all nodes were shown. But not rows heights